# MS Identity Azure app registered but sends unauthorized_client in implicit flow

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, implicit-flow, microsoft-identity-platform

I have registered an app in Azure for Microsoft Identity platform. I configured it to allow MS Accounts (e.g. outlook.com) and have basically done everything in a few of the quickstarts online [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-access-web-apis) (except for "add credentials to your web app"). I have also checked the boxes that enable implicit flow.

I redirect my React application to the URL to sign in (using implicit flow), I get to enter my username but then I see

> unauthorized_client: The client does not exist or is not enabled for consumers. If you are the application developer, configure a new application through the App Registrations in the Azure Portal at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2083908

Like I mentioned above, I've gone through several quick starts and read about implicit flow [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow) and followed their examples for my code.

I also tried just deleting the app registration and starting over. No luck.

### JS Code attempting to implement Implicit Flow

JS code that redirects the browser to a Url that looks like Microsoft's first example on their [implicit flow page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow)

```js
goSignIn() {
    const tenant = 'common'; // (for us with MS accounts)
    const clientId = '*****';
    const redir = encodeURIComponent('http://localhost:3000/signin');
    const nonce = Math.round(Math.random() * 10000, 0);
    const uriTemplate = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={clientId}&response_type=id_token+token&redirect_uri={redirect}&scope=openid&response_mode=fragment&state={state}&nonce={nonce}';
    const filledTemplate = uriTemplate
      .replace('{tenant}', tenant)
      .replace('{clientId', clientId)
      .replace('{redirect}', redir)
      .replace('{nonce}', nonce)
      .replace('{state}', nonce);
    console.log(filledTemplate);
    window.location = filledTemplate;
  }
```

### App Configuration in Azure:

Azure -> Identity -> App Registrations -> MyApp -> Authentication

- Redirect Uri: http://localhost:3000/signin (React app runs on 3000 and I have a route configured for /signin)
- Not using any suggested Redirects.
- Checked Implicit checkboxes for ID Token and Access Token
- Live SDK support enabled
- Supported account types is set to "Accounts in any organizational directory and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox, Outlook.com)"

Azure -> Identity -> App Registrations -> MyApp -> API Permissions

- MS Graph

  - User.Read
  - Email
  - Profile
  - openid

From the docs I read, I *thought* I had done enough to the id token. I'm not sure what tweak must be made in order to get it to work.

Comment: I was having the same error. Realized I was using the wrong ID. The ID which we should use is in Overview tab named as Application (client) ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you have done enough to get the token. I have tested this on my side, it works well. Here I provide you with my screenshot for you to check again.

[image]

[image]

Also, here is my working request url, you can login with your msa to have a test.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=5fd66168-7ba3-4bbc-a155-bff662eed9f7
&response_type=id_token+token
&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/signin
&scope=openid
&response_mode=fragment
&state=12345
&nonce=678910
```

Comment: Hello I have the same problem, but the screenshot you shared does not match with the current view of the page, moreover I donot understand what needs to be changed, I am using the same url @TonyJu suggested at the end

Answer (score 10):

I experienced an issue like this one. The mistake I made has to do with the App ID: when you create the client secret the Azure UI will present the secret and the secret ID. This secret ID is *not* the one to use in your app's configuration. Rather, you need the Application ID found on the Overview page.

I imagine that there are many configuration problems which can produce this error message. In general: pay close attention to the App ID, if the error is that the app is not found.

Comment: That was my problem indeed, thank you!

Comment: Thank you, this a experience Issue in Azure Portal, you save my life 

Comment: I too ran into this, terrible UX to be honest but par for the course for Azure.